# Custom Transition Over Current Context

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out how to access the functionality of `.overCurrentContext` while making custom transitions in Swift 4.

The goal is to have an application with a `UIViewController` that is embedded inside of a container and has a `UIButton` which presents a different VC without hiding the elements of the container.

I've used `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate` methods in the past but I can't figure out how to make it work with a `.overCurrentContext` presentation style.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Set `modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext` in the init of VC that is beeing presented.

Comment: It is a custom transition, therefore the modalPresentationStyle has to be .custom

Comment: I've created a project to test it. You could check it [here](https://github.com/TomaszPietrowski/CustomTransitionOverCurrentContexExample). I'm not sure it meets your requirements but I hope it will help.